# Creating Rank Variable in Hive 0.09

Tags: hive, hql, hiveql

I'm stuck with the version of Hive for the time being, but would like to create a rank variable within Hive 0.09. Additionally, I'd like to avoid using Hive's built-in function creator if possible. I know in later versions it should look like:

```
create table temp as select
id,
date_field,
time_field,
rank() over (id, date_field, time_field) as rank
from orig_table
order by id, date_field, time_field;
```

I've been banging my head against the walls on this one for a couple hours. Any ideas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know its horribly inefficient, but the date/time is limited to 30 combinations max... so I created 30 tables, joined them all together, and essentially ranked along rows instead of columns.